# show google maps in uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I created a subclass of UIView and paste it into MyViewController. In MyViewController I'm trying to insert a Google , but it does not affect ( just a white screen). But if I try to insert code into the likeness of that everything is working fine.

```
// this code work good 
UIAlertView *helloWorldAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"My First App" message:@"Hello, World!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display the Hello World Message
    [helloWorldAlert show];
```

What do I need to do that would be reflected subclass of UIView Google maps?

```
// this is my code and this is not work


GMSMapView *mapView_;
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"#######"];



GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:1];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically add the mapView_ as a subview of your UIView.

You can refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27624729/4195406) posted in your other question.

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(YOUR_MAP_X, YOUR_MAP_Y, YOUR_MAP_WIDTH, YOUR_MAP_HEIGHT);
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I do not even know how to thank you , I'm on a solution to this problem has spent the week

Comment: I have one more question , the card works , thanks, but missing key user detection (I mean it just is not reflected on the map , at what markers remained in place ) - How to get her back ?

Comment: not quite sure what you meant by user interaction, but your can enable user interaction for your view. You can do something like `yourView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: I mean, I have stopped working line mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;